# How to convert nested string representation of lists into list in python using pandas or any simple method?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

```
[ '[{ growth=FLOW, label=BOW} ]',                                                                 
 '[{ growth=FLOW1, label=BOW1}, {growth=MID1, label= pow1} ]', 
'[{growth=FLOW2, label=BOW2}, {growth=MID1, label= pow1} ]'  ]
```

How I can remove the string format and make it actual lists of the list.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

eg: Data Sample

```
           date                      cord                  bound_box
0     2020-08-07T02:40:25     14.1561926,121.2731238      '[{width=0.05, x=0.46879336, growth_state=EARLY, y=0.44942817, label=CLERT, height=0.05}]'
                                                    
1     2020-07-22T23:36:35     37.2349683,-80.4365232        '[{width=0.05, x=0.43004116, growth_state=BRANCHING, y=0.48765433, label=CIRVU, height=0.05}]'

2     2020-08-25T01:17:35     14.1737223,121.2563773     '[{width=0.05, x=0.43387097, growth_state=MID, y=0.37651333, label=MIMPU, height=0.05}]'
3     2020-04-27T18:04:10     53.0833487,-2.0382104     '[{width=0.05, x=0.31318682, growth_state=MID, y=0.52674896, label=GAETE, height=0.05}, {width=0.05, x=0.7967033, growth_state=EARLY, y=0.7105624, label=GAETE, height=0.05}, {width=0.05, x=0.35897437, growth_state=MID, y=0.3058985, label=GAETE, height=0.05}]'
```

also there is a slight mistake in answer @pts. Could you please correct it, as you have merged the sublist too.

```
current format in third column ==> [ '[]', '[{}, {}]', '[{}, {}, {}]',... ]
Desired Format ==> [ [],  [{}, {}],  [{}, {}, {}],... ]
```

Data sample (as requested by @pts) to give some context to the reader why we need to do such data preprocessing? The main aim is to make each list and its inside dictionary to its normal form so that, finally, we can flatten the third column (bound_box) per each list. I hope @pts you will get some idea why I was trying to do so.  Also apart from using regular expression is there any simple way to process lists of the third column, so that noob like me could understand and thank you for your answer.

Comment: The strings are not Python code

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works in Python:

```py
import re
data = r'''
[ '[{ growth=FLOW, label=BOW} ]'                                                
'[{growth=FLOW2, label=BOW2}, {growth=MID1, label= pow1} ]'  ]
'''
data = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z{}=]+', ' ', data)
data = re.sub(r'= *', '=', data)
data = re.sub(r'} *{', '\n', data)
data = re.sub(r'[{} ,]+', ' ', data)
data = re.sub(r' *\n *', '\n', data).strip(' \n')
data = re.sub(r'(\S+)=(\S+)', r"'\1': '\2',", data)
data = '[%s]' % ', '.join(
    '{%s}' % line.rstrip(',') for line in data.split('\n'))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'growth': 'FLOW', 'label': 'BOW'}, {'growth': 'FLOW', 'label': 'BOW'}, {'growth': 'MID', 'label': 'pow'}, {'growth': 'FLOW', 'label': 'BOW'}, {'growth': 'MID', 'label': 'pow'}]
```

It uses regular expression substitutions to transform the string in multiple steps. To see how it works in more detail, you may want to add `print(data); print('')` lines between the `data = ...` lines.

Detailed explanation of this line follows:

```py
data = re.sub(r'(\S+)=(\S+)', r"'\1': '\2',", data)
```

In the line above the regular expression is `(\S+)=(\S+)`. `\S` matches a non-whitespace character (e.g. `g`), `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters (e.g. `growth`), `=` matches itself, and the parentheses make the matched characters available as `\1` and `\2` in the replacement. The replacement is `'\1': '\2'`, and `\1` will be substituted with the characters matched by the first `\S+`, and `\2` will be substituted with the characters matched by the second `\S+`. The `re.sub` call replaces all occurrences from left to right, non-overlapping. An example: it replaces `growth=FLOW` with `'growth': 'FLOW',`.

Comment: wow @pts, your code is working but as I am a newbie,  I did not understand how your code has converted those irregular forms of the dictionary into the normal form. I can see you have used regular expressions.

I want to know how this is working so that I can convert the whole data frame series into usable form. Actually, I am working on one dataset which has this problem. Dictionary is not in python dictionary format. Also, the list is in string format.

Comment: To get a more specific and useful answer to your question, give some input--output pairs as examples. (Your question only contains an example input.) You may want to specify how the Pandas output should look like.

Comment: To learn more about regular expressions, find tutorials online. I'm adding an explanation of one of the lines to my answer to help you.

Comment: The official tutorial on using regular expressions in Python is good: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html